# How many ways can we arrange a string cointaining x 0's and y 1's?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can we arrange a string cointaining x 0's and y 1's?

Example 6 zeroes, 8 ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $x+y$ total numbers. There are $(x+y)!$ ways to arrange the numbers if they were distinct. In this case, they are not, so you need to divide $(x+y)!$ by $x!$ to account for the zeros and $y!$ to account for the ones. The final formula is $\frac{(x+y)!}{x!y!}$. [Here](https://www.boundless.com/algebra/textbooks/boundless-algebra-textbook/combinatorics-and-probability-343/combinatorics-57/permutations-of-nondistinguishable-objects-240-10908/) is a general source to help you get the idea. I also suggest that you look into [Stars and Bars](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), as this specific problem could also be solved using that method.

Comment: Aaha, just 14C6 then. Thank you!